# How can i use google docs in my .net project

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I use Google Docs to display an Excel spreadsheet or document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this

For API

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/

How to code

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html

Comment: ya, we can find the right content which i had used in the URL given here @Dorababu

Comment: The .Net link needs to be updated: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Add a hyperlink to your Google Docs URL.